# Django Rest Framwork return serializer create() method response from view?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to bulk entry of product order. Here are my two models; one is Order and another is OrderMap.

Order model is summary of order and OrderMap stores all of product order details. I have written a create method in OrderSerializer and everything is working ok but I cannot trigger response to the view. How to do it?

Here is my code:

**serializers.py**

```
class OrderMapSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    OrderNo = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='order.orderno')

    class Meta:
        model = OrderMap
        fields = ('id', 'OrderNo', 'ItemCode', 'OrderQty', 'ReceivedQty')


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    OrderMapData = OrderMapSerializer(many=True, source='ordermaporder')

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ordermap_set = validated_data.pop('ordermaporder')
        add_pro = Order.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for data in ordermap_set:
            OrderMap.objects.create(
                OrderNo=add_pro,
                OrderQty=data.get('OrderQty'),
                ItemCode=data.get('ItemCode'),
                ReceivedQty=data.get('ReceivedQty')
            )
        return add_pro
```

**I want to return response from my view like this:**

```
if():
     dict_response = {"error": False, "Title": "Success", "ico": "successIcon", "message": "Wellcome! Product item successfully added."}

else:
     exceptions = []
     for key in serializer.errors.keys():
     exceptions.append({"field": key, "message": serializer.errors[key][0]})
     dict_response = {
                    "error": True,
                    "status": 400,
                    "message": "Your submitted data was not valid - please correct the below errors",
                    "exception": exceptions
                }

return Response(dict_response)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it like this:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = OrderSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        order = serializer.save()
        serializer = OrderSerializer(order)
        dict_response = {"error": False, "Title": "Success", "ico": "successIcon", "message": "Wellcome! Product item successfully added."}
        return Response(dict_response)
    else:
        exceptions = []
        for key in serializer.errors.keys():
            exceptions.append({"field": key, "message": serializer.errors[key][0]})
            dict_response = {
                "error": True,
                "status": 400,
                "message": "Your submitted data was not valid - please correct the below errors",
                "exception": exceptions
            }
    return Response(dict_response)
```